# Analytic works versus synthetic works in mathematical research

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, terminology, philosophy, research

With the purpose to clarify my ideas about terminology I would like to ask in Mathematics Stack Exchange what is **the difference of two verbal expressions**: when a professional mathematician understands that a contemporary and remarkable work in mathematical research (you can to think in historic papers/articles, thesis, books, monographs or a work that corresponds to a mention of an award) is mainly a synthetic work and when, in contrast, the professional mathematician considers that the work of his/her colleague was mainly analytic.

> **Question.** Provide a clarification about when a mathematician understands, that a great mathematical work due to a contemporary mathematician, is mainly synthetic and when the mathematician should to undestand that such work is mainly analytic. **Many thanks.**

If there is some reference from the literature that you want or need to refer in the discussion about what is the difference of the terms analytic and synthetic referred in the context of mathematical research, please feel free to answer the question as a reference request.

Comment: See [Analysis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analysis/)

Comment: And Hintikka, [The Method of Analysis](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Method_of_Analysis/XwrvCAAAQBAJ) as well as [Method of Analysis: A Paradigm of
Mathematical Reasoning?](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01445340.2011.594600)

Comment: If you consider it, feel free to add your reference in the body of an answer for this  Standford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, and expand your answer according the references, or yourself clarification that yoy want to explain. @MauroALLEGRANZA Many thanks for your feedback. A

Comment: Please feel free to add your discussion, that I've read, as an answer. Many thanks for your attention @AlexKruckman

Comment: Is this motivated by any particular instance of these terms in mathematics that you've seen?

Comment: I was inspired @NoahSchweber (thus it is just my interpretation) in a talk in Spanish by professor Fernando Zalamea Traba (when he mentions in Spanish "los grandes maestros"), the video with title *Entrevista Fernando Zalamea* from the channel of YouTube **Colectivo DON´T PANIC**, at date 2013, 26th July. Many thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Professional mathematicians do not classify research as synthetic or analytic. The [analytic/synthetic distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%E2%80%93synthetic_distinction) comes from philosophy, and it is very rare for mathematicians to use these words in their philosophical senses. Based on my experience, I believe few mathematicians are even aware of these philosophical concepts, and ever fewer could give definitions of "analytic proposition" and "synthetic proposition". (I belong to the middle camp: I'm aware that the analytic/synthetic distinction is a thing, but I don't think I could adequately define these terms.)

I have never heard a mathematician describe research as analytic or synthetic. The exception is in the context of analysis as a mathematical discipline and fields like synthetic differential geometry or analytic number theory that have these words in their name. But here the mathematicians are using these words refer to the discipline, not the philosophical analytic/synthetic distinction - even if e.g. the use of the term "synthetic" in "synthetic differential geometry" can possibly be traced back to the philosophical concept.

Comment: As soon I study it in next few days I should to accept an answer for my post. Many thanks.

Comment: I hope to wait more days before choosing an answer, but I think yours is very good. Therefore thank you very much, I'm going to accept it now.

Comment: There is an exception to your first sentence, namely classical geometry: synthetic geometry often refers to Euclidean geometry, i.e. geometry from an axiomatic perspective; whereas analytic geometry often refers to Cartesian coordinate geometry, i.e. geometry with coordinates, with equations for various types of curves, and with applications of algebra. However, the drift that I catch is that this example is precisely the opposite of the philosophical meaning of the analytic/synthetic distinction.