# Is there a mathematical definition of when a true mathematical statement is analytic or synthetic?

Tags: soft-question, definition, philosophy

I know that, in philosophy, there is the distinction between analytic and synthetic statements. I wonder, has anyone formalized this difference in a mathematical way? Like, is there a mathematical definition that can sort true mathematical statements into analytic and synthetic statements? Or, is there simply no such thing as a true synthetic mathematical statement?

Comment: What definition of ,"synthetic" are you using?  Broadly, I'd have said it referred to propositions which could be confirmed or refuted by talk world observations. I'm which case, I personally would not think there are such claims in mathematics.

Comment: But I could see where someone could make a case for saying that claims which can be settled by a finite computer search are synthetic, at least in some sense.

Comment: I don't think we'd consider a proposition true unless it's been proven ("analytically"). Math concepts model, but don't actually refer to, physical things, so real-world observations can supply intuition about them but not prove them.

Comment: For instance, the claim that $1729$ is the least natural number which is the sum of two cubes in two different ways feels at least a little synthetic.

Comment: [A related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4438219/analytic-works-versus-synthetic-works-in-mathematical-research?rq=1), particularly [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4439229).

Comment: The way I was told "analytic" and "synthetic" meant in the history of philosophy and mathematics is that "analytic" statements are decided only with reference to the definition, and anything else was synthetic, requiring "other steps" (like constructions in geometry) to bridge the gap to the solution. So, for example, "a square is a rectangle" doesn't require anything more than analyzing the terms.  But I agree this doesn't settle the question asked, I'm just throwing it out there.

Comment: I agree with @rscwieb,  the distinction, in philosophy, between synthetic /analytic isn’t related to the connection of the statement to experience or observation.  ‘Analytic’ are those judgments whose predicate is contained in the subject, in the definition:  they analyze the concept expressed in the subject.  The distinction *coming from experience/ not coming from experience* is the distinction, of Kantian origin,  between *a posteriori/ a priori*.